# How to resolve Forbidden error while making Get and Post Request in Xero API

Tags: dynamics-crm, power-automate, xero-api

I was using **Xero API** for a long time but a few days ago I encountered an error which I wasn't able to resolve even though I don't understand what's going wrong. The thing was that a few days ago **Xero API** started throwing **forbidden errors** when I tried to find the root of the cause I was unable to find anything. Actually, I was using **power automate flows** to make *Get* and *Post* Requests using **Xero API**, and also made a flow that automatically renew my *access token* just before when it's going to expire, the *access token* renewal flow was working fine properly but other request I was making using *Get* or *Post* method it's showing **Forbidden error**.

I am attaching some of the screenshots where I got the issue, I hope it might help.

Thanks

[Xero API for Renewing Access token is still working fine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcfWM.png)

[Xero API using Get method showing me this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQ2gE.png)

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP 403 was thrown because the Demo Company that you were using has expired.

There are a few reasons why you could be hitting a 403.

- The Access Token being used is expired and must be refreshed
- The Tenant ID being used in the headers is missing
- The user has revoked access
- The permissions of the User who set up the connection have changed:  If the user who has authorised the connection between the    API application and the Xero tenant is removed from accessing that    tenant, or their role changes so that they can longer authorise API    connections, then the connection will no longer be authorised
- The Tenant is no longer active: This generally occurs when an organisation has been deleted, the free trial has ended or a demo organisation has been reset.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.
When I was using the same credentials to renew access token and it was working fine.
also having one more issue when i make a request to get the details about the tenant i'm getting blank array, does it means that i don't have any tenant to use with that authorized api calls.

Comment: Could you please suggest to me what do I have to do to make it work again as i was the owner of that account the role can't be changed and as the tenant was removed how can I add it again?

Answer (score 0):

The tenant was a Demo Company and demo companies reset after 28 days. When the reset happens a new Demo Company is built and this has a different tenant id.

Any app connections will break due to the reset so you would need to go through the authorization steps  again to connect the Demo Company to your app.

Please note, tokens can be refreshed even if the connection is deleted. The GET Connections request will be empty if the connection is deleted so this is how you know there are no active connections for the token.

Comment: @doel , thanks for explaining the issue reasons.
Thanks to you too **Sally** for explaining the whole scenario in such an easy language now I got it, **thank you** again.